# Python: For loop should read one row of a column per iteration

Tags: python, selenium, automation

I have the following problem: My program is supposed to enter data from an Excel table onto a web page. The problem is that I have several rows in my dataframe and I would like to address the upcoming row of column XY on each pass to take the data from the field. For example, in the first pass I want to save the first row of column XY and in the second pass the second row and so on. This is my code, this gives me all the values at once in each iteration. Thus, all existing values from the rows of column XY are entered into the web field with Selenium and I do not want that.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    search.send_keys(row["XY"])
´´´
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use iterrows with enumerate

```
for i, (index, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i == 2:
        search.send_keys(row["XY"])
        break
```

This code will only read the 3rd row and will stop there.

Comment: Thank you. But I need something that reads the first row in the first pass and then the second row in the second pass and so on.